# bootstrap- form-control overriding col-sm-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a login page in bootstrap 3.3.6.I have set col-sm-3 for the form but the input having class="form-control" overrides this and is displayed in full screen. If I remove the class="form-control" from input then it works fine. why is this? How do I fix this?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<form closs="col-sm-3">
 
<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email </label> 
<input type="email"  placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control"></input>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password </label> 
<input type="password"  placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control"></input>

</div>


<button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using class="input-group". I still don't get the reason.

```
<form closs="col-sm-3">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="email">Email </label> 
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email"  placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control">        </input>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password </label> 
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email"  placeholder="Enter email" class="form-control">    </input>
</div>

</div>


<button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using this demo and add CSS and JS

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```